# Translating SOAP to PHP call function

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to learn how to use SoapUI to integrate Web Services to my website. I've been trying to follow PHP's documentation, but it is very confusing. My question is: how can I translate this soap code to PHP, so I can call the SOAP function. This is what I got so far:

```
  $wsdl = "http://api.rlcarriers.com/1.0.2/ShipmentTracingService.asmx?wsdl";

  $request = [
'APIKey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'traceNumbers' => $pro,
'TraceType' => 'PRO',
'FormatResults' => 'false',
'IncludeBlind' => 'false',
'OutputFormat' => 'Standard'
];

  $client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

  $result = $client->TraceShipment($request);  

  print_r($result);
```

However, this is not working. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I appreciate any help provided. I've spent hours trying to figure it out and it's driving me crazy. This is the soap request code that I get with SoapUI by following this wsdl file: http://api.rlcarriers.com/1.0.2/ShipmentTracingService.asmx?wsdl

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:rlc="http://www.rlcarriers.com/">
       <soap:Header/>
       <soap:Body>
          <rlc:TraceShipment>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <rlc:APIKey>******************</rlc:APIKey>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <rlc:request>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <rlc:TraceNumbers>
                   <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                   <rlc:string>143248716</rlc:string>
                </rlc:TraceNumbers>
                <rlc:TraceType>PRO</rlc:TraceType>
                <rlc:FormatResults>false</rlc:FormatResults>
                <rlc:IncludeBlind>false</rlc:IncludeBlind>
                <rlc:OutputFormat>Standard</rlc:OutputFormat>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <rlc:CustomerData></rlc:CustomerData>
             </rlc:request>
          </rlc:TraceShipment>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: It appears that you've just posted your API key. You'll want to change/revoke it immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First mistake is to use the function name as a method of the `SoapClient`.

Correct is to use native method [SoapClient::__soapCall()](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) and the function name use as first parameter like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$result = $client->__call('TraceShipment', $request);
```

For easier debugging use the try...catch block that gave you access to messages returned from the server:

```
try {
  $result = $client->__soapCall('TraceShipment', $request);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  print_r($e);
  print_r($client);
}
```

Second mistake
The arguments `$request` should be an array of associative array, ie two *level array*, to be accepted by SoapServer:

```
$request = [[
  //...
]];
```

Third mistake
The mandatory arguments are

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="APIKey" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="request" type="tns:ShipmentTracingRequest"/>
```

So do update your `$request` array by the `request` key (updated based on Carlos post):

```
$request = [[
      'APIKey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'request' => [
          'TraceNumbers' => [
              'string' => $pro
          ],
          'TraceType' => 'PRO',
          'FormatResults' => 'false',
          'IncludeBlind' => 'false',
          'OutputFormat' => 'Standard'
      ]
]];
```

---

When fixed you could get response like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [TraceShipmentResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [WasSuccess] => 1
            [Messages] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

            [Result] => stdClass Object
                (
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with my $request array because that didn't seem to work. I get something like this: SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => looks like we got no XML document [string:Exception:private]

Comment: @Carlos I have updated my answer with two level array of the argument variable.

Comment: Your "first mistake" is wrong. Unless you need to pass extra arguments, or don't have a WSDL, you shouldn't need to call `__soapCall` directly at all. On the other hand, using `__soapCall` requires you to pass the parameters in a *different* format, further muddling the problem. See the official and user-contributed notes on this manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

Comment: Still not working. I get this now: SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: For me it works...even using this is a low level API function `__soapCall()`

Comment: @ino that works! Just one more thing... I'm trying to echo the results like this: echo $result->TraceShipmentResult->Result->Shipment->ShipmentNumber; but it's not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have received empty response so I cannot test it... Anyway you got some valid response from the SoapServer so now it will be piece of cake to finish it, won't be :)

Comment: You are welcome. ...and pls, accept the answer to let know other guys struggling with SOAPClient that this thread could help them to start with it.

Comment: @ino I think I know why it has to be a two-level array. The 'request' field on the wsdl should another array, but then that would leave the API in the first level, no? I am also getting a blank response even with my API key.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anyone will ever need this, but I figured out the problem. I'm just learning about SOAP now, and realized that in order to translate the SOAP call to PHP one needs to treat all tags as arrays. Therefore, given the structure of the request call, the PHP request should look like this:

```
$request = array(
    'APIKey' => '***********************',
    'request' => array(
        'TraceNumbers' => array(
            'string' => $pro
            ),
        'TraceType' => 'PRO',
        'FormatResults' => 'false',
        'IncludeBlind' => 'false',
        'OutputFormat' => 'Standard'
    )
);
```